# Sharing Opcache between multiple instances of PHP-FPM

Tags: php, opcache

I have two servers running the same application through PHP-FPM with sessions stored in a shared location.

Is there a way to have a shared Opcache between the two servers? Is it safe to use `opcache.file_cache` for this?

Comment: My question is, do you think that transferring OpCache content from one server to another is faster than reading and "compiling" a file and storing the resulting opcodes in local memory?

Comment: My gut says no, but I'd like to benchmark it to know for sure. Related to this I'm wondering if I can add another server (autoscaling) with a prepopulated Opcache somehow.

Comment: I've spotted [this github repository](https://github.com/engineyard/ey-php-performance-tools/tree/master/zend-primer) which might work combined with `opcache.file_cache` being enabled if you add it to your deploy process and then make an image of your server with the opcache pre-populated for the purposes of creating an image that can then be launched with the file cache pre-populated. Not tried this myself though.